# Angular 5 validation form

Tags: html, validation, typescript, mean

i'm building a meanstack application and i'm doing the validation for some forms now.
evrything works fine but the paragraph '

' with the error message is not showing.
Also their should be a red textbox if the field is not valid.
I wrote some code but I can't find my error.

Here is my html file :

```
    <h2>Add employee</h2>

<form (submit)="addEmployee($event)" name="myForm"  #f="ngForm">
  <pre>{{f.value | json}}</pre>
  <pre>Valid? {{f.form.controls.email?.valid}}</pre>
<pre>Dirty? {{f.form.controls.email?.dirty}}</pre>
<pre>Touched? {{f.form.controls.email?.touched}}</pre>
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
      'has-danger': f.form.controls.name?.invalid && (f.form.controls.name?.dirty || f.form.controls.name?.touched),
      'has-success': f.form.controls.name?.valid && (f.form.controls.name?.dirty || f.form.controls.name?.touched)
    }">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" minlength="5" required>


  <div class="form-control-feedback"
     *ngIf="name.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
  <p *ngIf="name.errors.required">Name is required</p>
  <p *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">Name must contain minimum 5 characters</p>
</div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="age" name="age"  required>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
      'has-danger': f.form.controls.email?.invalid && (f.form.controls.email?.dirty || f.form.controls.email?.touched),
      'has-success': f.form.controls.email?.valid && (f.form.controls.email?.dirty || f.form.controls.email?.touched)
    }">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="email" (ngModelChange)="email = $event" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" name="email"  required>

  <div class="form-control-feedback"
     *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
  <p *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</p>
  <p *ngIf="email.errors.minlength">Email must contain at least the @ character</p>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="wage">Wage:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="wage" name="wage"  required >
  </div>
  <label for="error" [(ngModel)]="error" class="error"></label>

  <button type="submit"  (click)="reload()" [disabled]="f.invalid" (submit)="addEmployee($event)" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my typescript file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Import the DataService
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

import { UserService } from '../../user.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

//define an array for all the employeeees
  employees: Array<any>;
  name : string = '';
  age = 0;
  wage = 0;
  email : string = '';
  username : string;
  error:string;

myform : FormGroup;

  ngOnInit()
  {

  }

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private userService : UserService) {

      //get thee employees from de datasrvice ...:D
    this._dataService.getEmployees()
        .subscribe(res => {this.employees = res;});
    this.username = this. userService.getNameUserLoggedIn();
  }


    addEmployee(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.username == ''){
            alert("You have to log in before you can add an employee !")           
        }
        else{
        var newEmployee = {
            name: this.name,
            age : this.age,
            wage : this.wage,
            email : this.email, 
            user : this.username            
        }        
        this._dataService.addEmployee(newEmployee)
        .subscribe(employee => {
                this.employees.push(employee);
                this.name = '';
                this.age = 0 ;
                this.wage = 0;
                this.email = '';

            });
    }}
    reload() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <--create code in Html  for Component.html-->
        <-- Important for Create for Component.ts file 
     export class in only create    user: any={}   -->     



        <div class="container">
              <form class="form" id="custForm" name="custForm" #custForm='ngForm'>
              <div class="form-body">      
                  <h3 class="box-title m-t-40">Registration</h3>      
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row"> 
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control"  required  placeholder="Name" name='name' #name='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="user.Name">
                 <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="text-danger">
                    <div [hidden]="!name.hasError('required')">Name is required</div>                 
                         </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="^\w+([\.-]? 
                     \w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" placeholder="Email Id" id="email" 
                     name='email'#email='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="user.Email"> 
                             <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine" class="text-danger">
                              <div [hidden]="!email.hasError('required')">Email is required</div>
                              <div [hidden]="!email.hasError ('pattern')">Email format should be
                                  <small><b>shree@abc.com</b></small>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Mobile</label>
                            <input type="text" #Contact="ngModel" required pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" id="Contact" name='Contact' minlength=10 maxlength=10
                                  [(ngModel)]="user.Contact" class="form-control">
                                <div [hidden]="Contact.valid || Contact.pristine " class="text-danger">
                                  <div [hidden]="!Contact.hasError('required')">Mobile Number is required</div>
                                  <div [hidden]="!Contact.hasError('pattern')">Enter valid Mobile Number
                                    <small>
                                      <b>ex.7735676743</b>
                                    </small>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  required  placeholder="Username" name='Username' #Username='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="user.Username">
                            <div [hidden]="Username.valid || Username.pristine"
                            class="text-danger">
                            <div [hidden]="!Username.hasError('required')">Username is required</div>

                       </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control"  required  placeholder="Password" name='Password' #Password='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="user.Password">
                            <div [hidden]="Password.valid || Password.pristine"
                            class="text-danger">
                            <div [hidden]="!Password.hasError('required')">Password is required</div>

                       </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Country</label>             
                          <select class="form-control" id="Country" name='Country' #Country='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="user.Country">
                            <option value=" " selected>Select</option>
                            <option value="India">India</option>
                            <option value="America">America</option>
                            <option value="Chaina">Chaina</option>

                          </select>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              <div class="form-actions">
                  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!custForm.valid" class="btn btn-success" (click)="recordSave()"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              </div>

              </div>
            </form>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value